# Set list item permissions in Workflow 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, permissions, sharepoint-addin

I've created a workflow inside an "App for SharePoint 2013" project. I need to set special permissions to the curent list item inside this workflow.

I read this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e2e59b58-8623-472b-8314-f2967e5271e9/sharepoint-2013-workflow-update-list-item-permissions-in-workflow, and learned how to make it in SPD, but I need to do it inside an app, in visual studio.

Did someone faced such problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to set permissions using REST API in Workflow that runs under App identity.

Please check [my blog post](http://spsite.pro/Blog/Post/3/SharePoint-2013-REST-API-%E2%80%93-How-to-set-Unique-Permissions-%28Item-Level-Permissions%29) about these methods:

- BreakRoleInheritance
- AddRoleAssignment

Also we have released a set of SharePoint 2013 Workflow activities to work with permissions - [Artezio SharePoint 2013 Workflow Activities](https://sp2013workflowactivities.codeplex.com). Please check.

Comment: Are both of these options available for o365 SPO? Is it possible call REST from Workflow 2013?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to call REST from Workflow 2013, activities can make it easier

Comment: The page is 404, please update or delete this answer because became useless.