# Is there a way for a group of users to upload documents but don't download them?

Tags: 2013, list, permissions

I would like to know if you know if there is a way for users to be able to upload documents to a certain folder but not read documents that other users upload.
For instance: 
      I upload a spreadsheet into SharePoint and then you upload another spreadsheet but you cannot see mine and I cannot see yours. (it would have to be the same folder)

Answer (score 2):

I presume you want something like [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/127991/item-level-permissions-settings-for-a-document-library-in-sharepoint-2013): Item level security settings for document libraries. But the answer isn't clear if it really works.

An other option is to write a event-receiver which updates the security on an item level as soon as it is uploaded.

Comment: Yes it works (it did in 2010), You can set Item-Level security in a Document Library with Powershell. The option is not available in the UI. I used this to distribute personal HR documents from an external system; PS script matched documents with AD accounts so everyone could only see their own reviews.

Answer (score 0):

you have several option:

The easiest way is to use only the ui in SP 2013. But be aware, if users have the direct link they will still be able to see the items, hovever not by just clicking through the ui.

Following Steps:

1. Go to Site Settings and to *Site Permissions* under *Users and Permissions*
2. Create a new Permission Level and make sure that "Manage Lists"Personal Permissions" are not checked. Save it with a name
3. Go to the List and break the permission inheritance and add a Group which has this permission level.
4. Put user which should only see their documents in that group (make sure that those users are not in any group that has the previous permissions activated)
5. create a new view which filters the items by "created by" with the [ME] placeholder

with that users should only see their documents and are not able to crete a personal view which let them see their other documents.

Thex next option is using a list 2013 workflow. every time a list item is created and breaks the inheritance of that item and sets it's own (to be precise, it sets the permission to the user who uploaded the document and maybe the manager or a manager group). This is described also here:
[Set list item permissions in Workflow 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77640/set-list-item-permissions-in-workflow-2013)

And the last option i know is already mention by Dribbel